# Visualize Historian Device Data in Watson IoT Platform: Issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, watson-iot

I am very new with IBM Bluemix, right now I'm working with a Raspberry Pi and IBM Watson Platform. I have followed this [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-partiii/)

And I can't storage the information, only the information is available in real time. furthermore in my Cloudant always says "one document" in  all the database for IBM Watson Platform. Is that correct? I'm not very familiar with database concepts.

I attached some screenshots of my problem: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ahes4in724opusv/AAAgEGYUVIJS76_o-NdJLx0Da?dl=0)

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates you have one database created for each day which implies you probably chose daily when configuring your bucket interval.

Please provide more details about what you mean when you say you can't store information and it's only available in real time - do you mean via your cards displayed in the dashboard? If so, you may wish to change the window size to greater than 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I choose daily configuration. My issue was that I couldn't view the historical data from my sensors in the dashboard, even when I changed the window size to 24 hours, but now the issue was solved by himself. I don't know what happen I only left my Raspberry Pi sending data to the cloud all the night. The next day I check my dashboard and it showed the historical data of that night. So, if anyone has a similar issue maybe you have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you've followed, has references to couple of other IoT Recipes to follow up, in the Conclusion section. The first IoT Recipe referred there, takes you through step by step instructions to setup Cloudant NoSQLDB as the Historian.

Continuing on the same lines, post completing the above mentioned steps, you can now walk through the steps mentioned in [Step 3 - Storing elevator device data using the Historical Data Storage Extension](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/storing-elevator-telemetry-and-alerts-in-cloudant-nosql-db/#r_step3) of the IoT Recipe "Store Elevator device data and alerts in Cloudant NoSQL DB", which shall help you configure your storage buckets as per the need, i.e days, weeks and months.